# Which is grammatically correct - "recidivisously" "recidivistly" or "recidivistically" as a valid adverb form of recidivist?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Per [How do you know if a derivative word is actually an English word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263382/how-do-you-know-if-a-derivative-word-is-actually-an-english-word) & its cited previous answer, [What are the criteria to adopt new words into English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english) - I am imagining that it is "recidivistically" in the sense of, e.g. "I am a recidivistically frugal Irishman."

To my hairy ears, "I am a recidivously frugal Irishman" rolls off the tongue better, but I don't know how to approach a resolve and suspect I am likely missing something very basic about how words work.  Oddly, "I am reidivously an unrepentant miser" seems correct.

Perhaps all are morphologically valid forms, and if so, is there any subtlety of difference in usage?

Perhaps none, and if so, is there valid and sound reason so?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is it a crime or a sin to be frugal?

Comment: @WeatherVane as far as I am aware, it is not; only so in a metaphorical and ironic sense of, e.g. "you cheap pr!ck!"

Comment: Well, I think you've invented a word.

Comment: Being frugal isn't the same as being a miser anyway.

Comment: ***recidivistic*** is in [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recidivistically) and [yourdictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/recidivistically), but I can't see the point of it in *I am a recidivistically frugal Irishman.* My perspective is that you wouldn't say *I am a **simplistically** frugal Irishman* (or *...a **simply** frugal Irishman*), so by the same token, I suggest *I am a **recidivist[ic]** frugal Irishman* is alll that's needed. Complexity for the sake of it is pointless, even when *regularly* forming new morphological derivations.

Comment: It's analogous to **euphemism=>euphemistically** :  **recidivism=>recidivistically**.  However, your particular example doesn't seem to fit very well for the reason Weather Vane brings up re crime.  Also, frugality is a general approach, not a discrete act, and recidivism is committing the same act again and again.

Comment: There are better words (that are more generally understood too), for example *unapologetic* and many other synonyms.

Comment: [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/recidivistically) lists **recidivistically** (not that that makes it a wise choice, as FumbleFingers points out).

Comment: I am an **unabashedly**  frugal Irishman." Recidivist does not work. Because you are Irish and being Irish is not a crime. It means to repeat the criminal act. So...This does not require a new word.

Comment: Any of the options are **grammatically** correct, to answer the question. Grammar doesn't distinguish real and made up words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "simplistically frugal" - I like that.  Thanks!